# Rails I18n put span around translated text if fallback was used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, translation

I'm using Rails built in I18n (Simple backend). I've set the default locale to :en and enabled fallbacks. Let's say I have translations for a specific item in English and Spanish. Now a German visitor comes to my site and it falls back to English. How would I go about detecting that fallback and wrapping it in a span?

`<span class="fallback">Hello</span>` instead of just `Hello`

This way I could then use client side machine translations.

I'm hoping to avoid writing my own backend to replace "Simple".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to resort to over-riding the translate function in I18n::Backend::FallBacks
https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/fallbacks.rb

```
module I18n
  module Backend
    module Fallbacks
      def translate(locale, key, options = {})
        return super if options[:fallback]
        default = extract_non_symbol_default!(options) if options[:default]

        options[:fallback] = true
        I18n.fallbacks[locale].each do |fallback|
          catch(:exception) do
            result = super(fallback, key, options)
            if locale != fallback
              return "<span class=\"translation_fallback\">#{result}</span>".html_safe unless result.nil?
            else
              return result unless result.nil?
            end
          end
        end
        options.delete(:fallback)

        return super(locale, nil, options.merge(:default => default)) if default
        throw(:exception, I18n::MissingTranslation.new(locale, key, options))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I just put this code in an initializer.

It feels very messy to me... I would still love to mark someone else's better answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution, using the metadata module from I18n. Also logs in a private log file to help spot missing translations. You can replace the calls with Rails.logger or remove them.

```
I18n::Backend::Simple.include(I18n::Backend::Metadata)

# This work with <%= t %>,but  not with <%= I18n.t %>
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module TranslationHelper
      alias_method :translate_basic, :translate
      mattr_accessor :i18n_logger

      def translate(key, options = {})
        @i18n_logger ||= Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/I18n.log")
        @i18n_logger.info "Translate key '#{key}' with options #{options.inspect}"
        options.merge!(:rescue_format => :html) unless options.key?(:rescue_format)
        options.merge!(:locale => I18n.locale)  unless options.key?(:locale)
        reqested_locale = options[:locale].to_sym
        s = translate_basic(key, options)
        if s.translation_metadata[:locale] != reqested_locale &&
           options[:rescue_format] == :html && Rails.env.development?

           @i18n_logger.error "* Translate missing for key '#{key}' with options #{options.inspect}"
           missing_key = I18n.normalize_keys(reqested_locale, key, options[:scope])
           @i18n_logger.error "* Add key #{missing_key.join(".")}\n"

          %(<span class="translation_fallback" title="translation fallback #{reqested_locale}->#{s.translation_metadata[:locale]} for '#{key}'">#{s}</span>).html_safe
        else
          s
        end
      end
      alias :t :translate

    end
  end
end
```

Then style with CSS

```
.translation_fallback {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.translation_missing {
  background-color: red;
}
```